# Search for a string in a php file with a start and end

Tags: php, regex, search

I'm having problems writing a php function to search for a certain text in a php file. I'm not good with regular expressions so I think that's the problem.

I need the regular expression to have a start word and end word and should return the text found in between.
This is what I tried:

```
$handle1 = fopen($file, "r");
$fileContents = fread($handle1,filesize($file));
if (preg_match('/'.$start. '((.|\n)*)'. $end.'/', $fileContents, $match)) {
$text=preg_split('/'.$start.'((.|\n)*)'. $end.'/', $match[0]);
echo $text. " found in $file<br/>";
}
```

Can anybody help please ?

Comment: Can you give an example of sample input, and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: As a side comment, my guess is you want the smallest match possible. If so, you need to make the match non-greedy : `(.|\n)*?`. Also, be careful with the `$start` and `$end` strings which can contain regex special characters.

Comment: What is the content of `$start` and `$end` ?

Comment: @krookedking I wanna search the whole file an return the result even if there are new lines.

Comment: @Femi I am not getting error but I can't get the result I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ...';

$start = 'sadipscing';
$end = 'dolore';

$pattern = sprintf(
    '/%s(.+?)%s/ims',
    preg_quote($start, '/'), preg_quote($end, '/')
);

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    list(, $match) = $matches;
    echo $match;
}
```

Where `$str` should be the contents of your file.

Have a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php for the `i`, `m` and `s` modifiers.

Comment: @Songo Now it will. See the `s` modifier. (last line of the answer)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need regex for this.

```
function getText($string, $start, $end)
{
   $text = "";
   $posStart = strrpos($string, $start);
   $posEnd = strrpos($string, $end, $posStart);
   if($posStart > 0 && $posEnd > 0)
   {
       $text = substr($string, $posStart, strlen($string) - $posEnd));
   }
   return $text;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I love these two solutions

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end)
{
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}


function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);   
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

I also made few benchmarks as well with both solutions above and both are giving almost the same time. You can test it as well. I gave both functions a file to read which had about 60000 characters (reviewed with Ms. Word's word count) and both functions resulted in about 0.000999 seconds to find.

```
$startTime = microtime(true);
GetBetween($str, '<start>', '<end>');
echo "Explodin Function took: ".(microtime(true) - $startTime) . " to finish<br />";

$startTime = microtime(true);
get_string_between($str, '<start>', '<end>');
echo "Subsring Function took: ".(microtime(true) - $startTime) . " to finish<br />";
```